# How to define a key/value table with 10 billion rows in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

```
k  | v
```

`k` is a unique string(varchar 32), `v` is also a string(varchar 50),

I will do these queries only:

```
insert into
select v from TABLE where k = "${k}"
```

How should I write my create table sql?

like partition in mysql? should I use it?

For example, should I use myisam or innodb?

I have many many read, and little insert, so the row level lock InnoDB might fit?

Comment: Do the math -- it will take months to batch load 10 billion rows into a table.  Do you really have that much data?  And how will you make use of it?  Fetching all the rows randomly will take about a century with spinning disks.

Comment: I just so want to put my pinky finger to the corner of my mouth, Dr.Evil-style...  "ten **beeel**-yun rows". "You know, I have one simple request. And that is to have sharks with frickin' laser beams attached to their heads! ..."

Comment: Is there mostly read or write activity on this table? You'll need to benchmark this pretty aggressively to ensure your system doesn't fall over. Write performance can nose-dive when you run out of IO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a test question?  Assuming we don't allow NULL values, and we don't allow duplicates, I'd opt for an index organized table:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable 
( k  VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL COMMENT 'pk (cluster key), ...'
, v  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'pk (cluster key), ...'
, PRIMARY KEY (k,v)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Most important is the cluster key, having 'k' be the leading column, because of the equality predicate in the WHERE clause.

If 'k' is guaranteed to be unique, then it alone can serve as the PRIMARY KEY.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable 
( k  VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL COMMENT 'pk (cluster key), ...'
, v  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COMMENT '...'
, PRIMARY KEY (k)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

This will prevent an INSERT from creating a row that has a duplicate value of 'k'.

In the worst case, if the assumptions about nullability and uniqueness aren't valid, then we're in a world of hurt in terms of providing a cluster key. We can let InnoDB use an internal identifier as the cluster key, and just create a covering index for our query, requiring approximately twice the space, due to overhead of the the internal identifier, and the separate index:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable 
( k  VARCHAR(32) COMMENT ''
, v  VARCHAR(50) COMMENT ''
, KEY mytable_IX1 (k,v)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

That's not nearly as efficient, but it does allow duplicates and for NULLs. Again, we want an index with a leading column of `k` (because of the equality predicate in the WHERE clause), and also including `v` (making it a covering index) so the SELECT query can be satisfied from the index pages, without needing to lookup pages in the underlying data table.

MySQL supports storage engines other than InnoDB. That's our best guess, absent any other specification regarding clustering, replication, and so on.

Assuming that `innodb_file_per_table` is enabled, I would consider partitioning. This isn't going to move the needle in terms of query performance, but this could improve manageability of the table, for example, if we wanted or needed to reorganize

```
  PARTITION BY RANGE (k) 
  ( PARTITION ke VALUES LESS THAN ('e')
  , PARTITION ki VALUES LESS THAN ('i')
  , PARTITION ko VALUES LESS THAN ('o')
  , PARTITION ku VALUES LESS THAN ('u')
  , PARTITION kz VALUES LESS THAN ('z')
  , PARTITION px VALUES LESS MAXVALUE
  )
```

Then we could reorganize a partition at a time:

```
  ALTER TABLE mytable REBUILD PARTITION ko;
```

Comment: The query he gave cannot match NULL keys, so if he's correct that it's the only one used, it's safe to say that keys are all NOT NULL. As for duplicate keys, if the prof is asking to allow that the student may well be better off leaving the course.

Comment: You're giving him too much credit for knowing what he needs.

Comment: So InnoDB is better than myisam even there is no transaction?

Comment: since myisam is table level lock and innoDB is row level lock, so InnoDB is better i guess?

Comment: MyISAM does have some advantages in some cases. The issues that would concern me are concurrency (InnoDB allows simultaneous DML and SELECT, MyISAM doesn't), automatic recovery in the event of a crash (MyISAM tables can get corrupted), buffer cache, etc. But a really big benefit is that InnoDB table has a cluster key, and rows are stored "in order". The table is effectively organized as an index. MyISAM table is stored as a heap, and requires secondary indexes. I wouldn't rule out MyISAM as an option, but would only choose MyISAM if there's good reason to.

Comment: There's several other storage engines. If the only important criteria was minimal space and blazing fast performance of INSERT and SELECT, as long as returning an empty set for every "`SELECT v FROM mytable WHERE ...`" query was acceptable, I'd even consider the BLACKHOLE storage engine, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blackhole-storage-engine.html